# How to change colors of the pie chart in d3pie

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify the following [code](http://jsfiddle.net/kamalakshan/g10ex773/) I saw online that uses the d3pie js. I can't seem to figure out how to change the colors? I am super new to Javascript and would like to use this chart on my website....

```
g.append("path")
        .attr("id", function(d, i) { return pie.cssPrefix + "segment" + i; })
        .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
            var color = colors[i];
            if (pie.options.misc.gradient.enabled) {
                color = "url(#" + pie.cssPrefix + "grad" + i + ")";
            }
            return color;
        })
```

Any clues? Kinda don't understand much :(

Comment: you can change color by changing colors array. Please try to be more specific; which color you want to change? This is picking up color conditionally if gradient is enabled then pick some from url else pick from array.

Comment: is it the segments array? @Zeeshan

Answer (score 0):

```
"data": {
    "content": [
        {
            "label": "Programación",
            "value": 6000,
            "color": "#82ccfb"
        },
        {
            "label": "Blogging",
            "value": 20,
            "color": "#FF0000"
        },
        {
            "label": "Ilustración / Arte",
            "value": 60,
            "color": "#395197"
        },
        {
            "label": "Diseño Gráfico",
            "value": 50,
            "color": "#457cda"
        },
        {
            "label": "Rotulación",
            "value": 20,
            "color": "#b0dae1"
        },
        {
            "label": "Agricultura",
            "value": 10,
            "color": "#062831"
        },
        {
            "label": "Diseño Web",
            "value": 80,
            "color": "#FF0000"
        }
    ]
},
```

It's at the end of the file in js. At the line number 2215. Check it. I change some colors.